# Parse JSON array to model .NET Core causes empty set

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-core, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

By calling `DbSet<T>.FromSqlRaw()` I can call a Stored Procedure in my Database, which returns a result set like this:

```
Id VARCHAR(36)
FirstName VARCHAR(255)
LastName VARCHAR(255) NULL
Email VARCHAR(255) NULL
Numbers VARCHAR(?) NULL
```

`Numbers` is a `VARCHAR` field which contains JSON array of `SearchContactsNumber`:

```
public sealed class SearchContactsNumber
{
    public Guid IdNumber { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

So, for instance, a result set could be like this:

```
"34f8d20f-21da-11eb-a249-de3268ec1e72" | "Paul" | "Newman" | "paul.newman@gmail.com" | "[{"IdNumber":"481d2957-21da-11eb-a249-de3268ec1e72","Type":"Telephone","Number":"+440001122333"},{...},{...}]"
```

Debugging the TestController.Index endpoint:

```
public sealed class SearchContacts
{
    public Guid IdContact { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SearchContactsNumber> Numbers { get; set; }
}

public class TestController : Controller
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;

    public TestController(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var set = _context.SearchContacts.FromSqlRaw<SearchContacts>($"CALL `SearchContacts`()");
        return Ok(set.ToList());
    }
}
```

returns:

[image]

How can I archieve full binding of the json string?

I'm using `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql (3.2.3)` with a MySQL 8 Database in a ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC Project.

Comment: Where are parsing the json string? Does ef core support parsing json data to objects automatically?

Comment: Maybe here is an answer to your question: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions Try to configure converting JSON string into object.

Comment: Youll need to get the value from the 5th column before parsing

Comment: @Nazar fact is that using that using `.Entity<T>` logic causes table creation during migration, which is not what I need, since that `SearchContacts` is a SP

Comment: So then you can retrieve the json as string and put in a property such as NumbersJson and change the Number property getter to return the result of the json string that is stored in the NumbersJson property by parsing as a list of SearchContactNumber

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pomelo introduced full-stack JSON support a couple of weeks ago, which is available in the latest Pomelo versions and will be used moving forward (previous approaches, like `JsonObject<T>` are now deprecated and are not officially supported in 5.0+ anymore).

To use it, you need to add one of the following packages, depending on which stack you want to use under the hood:

- `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Json.Microsoft`
- `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Json.Newtonsoft`

These packages support POCO classes, the stack-specific DOM APIs and simple string mapping.

We also support anything from top-level-only (very fast) to full (slower) change tracking for JSON entities (can be controlled via the `options` parameter of the `UseMicrosoftJson()` and `UseNewtonsoftJson()` methods).

Here is a fully working console sample project, that demonstrates how to use the full-stack JSON support of Pomelo for your particular case (here using the Microsoft stack):

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Infrastructure;

namespace IssueConsoleTemplate
{
    //
    // EF Core Entities:
    //
    
    public sealed class SearchContact
    {
        public Guid IdContact { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SearchContactsNumber> Numbers { get; set; }
    }
    
    //
    // JSON Entities:
    //
    
    public sealed class SearchContactsNumber
    {
        public Guid IdNumber { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Number { get; set; }
    }
    
    //
    // DbContext:
    //
    
    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<SearchContact> SearchContacts { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder
                .UseMySql(
                    "server=127.0.0.1;port=3306;user=root;password=;database=So64741089",
                    b => b.ServerVersion("8.0.21-mysql")
                          .CharSetBehavior(CharSetBehavior.NeverAppend)
                          .UseMicrosoftJson()) // <-- needed when using the Microsoft JSON stack (System.Text.Json)
                .UseLoggerFactory(
                    LoggerFactory.Create(
                        b => b
                            .AddConsole()
                            .AddFilter(level => level >= LogLevel.Information)))
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                .EnableDetailedErrors();
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<SearchContact>(
                    entity =>
                    {
                        entity.HasKey(e => e.IdContact);
                        
                        entity.Property(e => e.Numbers)
                            .HasColumnType("json"); // <-- simple way to serialize any property from/to JSON
                    });
        }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            using var context = new Context();

            SetupDatabase(context);

            var searchContacts = context.SearchContacts
                .FromSqlInterpolated($"CALL `SearchContacts`()")
                .ToList();

            Debug.Assert(searchContacts.Count == 1);
            Debug.Assert(searchContacts[0].Numbers.Count() == 1);
            Debug.Assert(searchContacts[0].Numbers.First().IdNumber == new Guid("481d2957-21da-11eb-a249-de3268ec1e72"));
        }

        private static void SetupDatabase(Context context)
        {
            context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();

            var connection = context.Database.GetDbConnection();
            connection.Open();

            using var command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = @"CREATE PROCEDURE `SearchContacts`()
BEGIN
    SELECT '34f8d20f-21da-11eb-a249-de3268ec1e72' as `IdContact`,
           'Paul' as `FirstName`,
           '[{""IdNumber"":""481d2957-21da-11eb-a249-de3268ec1e72"",""Type"":""Telephone"",""Number"":""+440001122333""}]' as `Numbers`;
END";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @IvanMonteiro If you mean, whether the `SearchContacts` procedure is mandatory for returning JSON from a MySQL database or not, then no. It is just what the OP wanted to achieve. For general use cases and methods to query JSON, see the sample code in [MySQL 5.7 Json Field Type Is Available Now
#14 (comment)](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/14#issuecomment-725257107).

Answer (score 2):

If you make it a JsonObject then serialization will be done automatically. The JsonObject is under System namespace and Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql support it 100%

see code below

```
using System;

public sealed class SearchContacts
{
    public Guid IdContact { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public JsonObject<SearchContactsNumber[]> Numbers { get; set; }

    public SearchContactsNumber[] GetNumbers()
    {
        return Numbers.Object;
    }
}
```

see: [How to use JsonObject of Pomelo.EntityFramework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62301095/how-to-use-jsonobject-of-pomelo-entityframework)

Comment: That's a nice and working solution BUT theres a problem: accessing object uses this horrible syntax `Numbers.First().Object.Number`. I would like to skip the `.Object.` "step" and write directly: `Numbers.First().Number`, is this possible?

Comment: Updated answer, you can add a method to make it easier, any other way you will have to serialize and deserialize yourself like MestreDosMagros answer, but it will be more code

Comment: `JsonObject<T>` is deprecated and was just removed from the 5.0 branch as planned. Both, `3.2.4` and `5.0.0-alpha.1` support full JSON support using both, the Microsoft and the Newtonsoft stack using an additional package. See [packages](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/#packages) on the official GitHub repo. I'll post an answer, how to use them.

Comment: @Trekco Actually, he hasn't said what version of Pomelo he is using. He has only stated, that he is using ASP.NET Core 3.1 and MySQL 8. Pomelo `3.2.4` is .NET Standard 2.0 compliant, so it is compatible with ASP.NET Core 3.1.

Comment: @lauxjpn are you the guy from GitHub repo? Anyway my Pomelo version in 3.2.3, I've just noticed there's a pending update in the NuGet Package Manager. I'm going to edit the question adding Pomelo version.

Comment: @EdoardoChiabra Yes, I am the lead developer of the Pomelo project.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
    public sealed class SearchContacts
    {
        public Guid IdContact { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Company { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SearchContactsNumber> Numbers { get; private set; }
        private string NumbersJson { set => Numbers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<SearchContactsNumber>>(value); }
    }
```

Just make sure you mapping the Numbers property to NumbersJson

Comment: Thought about it, and it is a fully working solution. What concerns me is the performance: everytime I access the field, deserialization fires.

Comment: Nops, is deserialized just on initialization

Comment: Only deserializes every time if you put the code on the getter instead of the setter

Comment: This snippet doesn't work. `Numbers` is `null` as in my example.

Comment: Did you mapped the numbers query result to the NumbersJson property?

Comment: Or just change the name of NumbersJson property to Numbers and Numbers property to something else...